# how one column can be large in a table

Tags: tables, texmaker, latexmk

I want to make a table that one of the columns must be fat! could some one fix it?

```
    \begin{table}[!h]\label{Table}
    \caption{random symmetrized instances}
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
Name  &   The generators of the symmetry group & Dimension & \\
 \hline
NS1     &   $(1,7,12,16,19,21,6)(2,8,13,17,20,5,11)(3,9,14,18,4,10,15),
  (4,6,5)(9,11,10)(13,15,14)(16,18,17)(19,20,21)$  &  21 \\
 \hline
NS2   &   $ (1,2,3,4,5)$  & 5
 \hline

    \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
    \end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: The table is just way too wide for the page. Consider splitting the entry into several lines (could perhaps use the `p{<width>}` specifier here?), or print the table sideways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tabularx` allows you to have a column "as wide as possible".

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!h]\label{Table}
  \caption{random symmetrized instances.}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{c>{\centering}Xc}
  \toprule
      Name  &   The generators of the symmetry group & Dimension  \\
  \midrule
  NS1     &   $(1,7,12,16,19,21,6)$, $(2,8,13,17,20,5,11)$, $(3,9,14,18,4,10,15)$,
  $(4,6,5)$, $(9,11,10)$, $(13,15,14)$, $(16,18,17)$, $(19,20,21)$  &  21 \\
  \midrule
  NS2   &   $ (1,2,3,4,5)$  & 5\\
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

There are different philosophies on the market that concern tables. Some say one should `bookmarks`, which I have done here. My personal philosophy, however, is that the best tables are those which one can avoid. ;-) Yet sometimes it is not possible to do that. Then `bookmarks` is a decent tool.